# What does this code written in rsf producer class do?

Tags: java, spring

Can any explain the following line written in rsf producer class?

Actually I am looking for next control flow

```
   UICommand.make(form, "saveSettings", UIMessage.make("administrate.save.settings.button"), null);
```

Comment: `rsf` or `jsf`? In the question title used `rsf` and in tagging used `jsf`?

Comment: @jubinPatel I think the OP is using [RSF](http://rsf.fluidproject.org/wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=Main). I created a new [tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rsf) for it.

Answer (score 1):

Copied from the Javadoc:

> Creates a command control which accepts a bound string (for example a UIMessage) as the textual label.

http://java2s.com/Open-Source/Java/Web-Framework/RSF/uk/org/ponder/rsf/components/UICommand.java.htm

You may also find additional info here: http://www2.caret.cam.ac.uk/rsfwiki/Wiki.jsp

This looks like a very old framework, last updated in 2008, why do you want to use it?